# extract optional field values from lines

Tags: regex, linux, unix, text-processing

I have text in the form of separate lines, where each line has CSV-like format:

```
SOME BUNCH OF TEXT, FIELD_A: 12, FIELD_B: 0.2321, FIELD_C: 12:10:08 2011/07/22, FIELD_D: 656
```

The order of fields is always the same, but some fields may be absent. There can be other fields between fields of interest, for example comparing to the line above I can get the following as well:

```
SOME BUNCH OF TEXT, FIELD_A: 12, NOT_INTERESTED: 235, FIELD_B: 0.2321, FIELD_C: 12:10:08 2011/07/22, FIELD_D: 656, FIELDS
```

As the result of processing this text I want to have clean CSV file with my fields specified one after another:

```
12,0.2321,12:10:08 2011/07/22,656
```

If some field is absent then I would like to simple omit value (for example FIELD_B was absent):

```
12,,12:10:08 2011/07/22,656
```

How can I do this using commands like sed, perl or awk ?
I tried extracting single field with `perl -pe 's/^.*?(FIELD_A: (.*?),)?.*?$/\2/'` and failed - regex simply ignores my field even if it presents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` with an associative array as shown below. Loop over the fields and split them on `:`. Then store the key-value pair into an associative array. Finally print out the fields you want.

```
awk -F, '{
 split("",arr)
 for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
   a=index($i, ":")
   if(a != 0){
     # split on first colon to get key-value pair
     key=substr($i,1,a-1)
     val=substr($i,a+1)

     # remove leading spaces from key and value
     gsub(/^ */,"",key)
     gsub(/^ */,"",val)

     # store in an associative array
     arr[key]=val
   }   
 }
 # print out the desired fields
 print arr["FIELD_A"]","arr["FIELD_B"]","arr["FIELD_C"]","arr["FIELD_D"]
}' data.txt
```

Comment: your solution works great. In fact I was expecting some regular expression as the solution, but seems that regex can't solve my problem. So we need to use script.

Answer (score 1):

How about this way (assuming fileds names are known) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @f = qw(FIELD_A FIELD_B FIELD_C FIELD_D);
while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @r;
    for(@f) {
        if ($line =~ /$_:\s*([^,]+)/) {
            push @r, $1;
        } else {
            push @r,'';
        }
    }
    print join(',',@r), "\n";
}
__DATA__
SOME BUNCH OF TEXT, FIELD_A: 12, FIELD_B: 0.2321, FIELD_C: 12:10:08 2011/07/22, FIELD_D: 656
SOME BUNCH OF TEXT, FIELD_A: 12, NOT_INTERESTED: 235, FIELD_B: 0.2321, FIELD_C: 12:10:08 2011/07/22, FIELD_D: 656, FIELDS
SOME BUNCH OF TEXT, FIELD_A: 12, NOT_INTERESTED: 235, FIELD_C: 12:10:08 2011/07/22, FIELD_D: 656, FIELDS
```

**output:**

```
12,0.2321,12:10:08 2011/07/22,656
12,0.2321,12:10:08 2011/07/22,656
12,,12:10:08 2011/07/22,656
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but get error `Can't locate Modern/Perl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at for_perl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at for_perl line 2.`   Seems like my version of perl is not modern :) I believe that it will work though for others with up-to-date version of perl.

Comment: @pavel_kazlou: just remove the line `use Modern::Perl;` an change `say` by `print`. See my edit.

Comment: Now this works for me, thanks. I've already up-voted your answer